# how to set up ms teams api integration for bubble.io app using api connector?

Tags: microsoft-teams, bubble.io

I want to enable my app users to create events in their ms teams accounts, what are the correct settings in the api connector?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on it. Do you want to send notification in Teams?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on it. Do you want to send notification in Teams?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT I am asking about the right authentication method and the right settings for this method and the cal I need to make. in bubble.io's api connector